# How to split equality of two lists?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I have the following goal and context:

```
  A : Type
  eqb : A -> A -> bool
  H : forall a1 a2 : A, eqb a1 a2 = true <-> a1 = a2
  x : A
  l1' : list A
  IHl1' : forall l2 : list A, eqb_list eqb l1' l2 = true <-> l1' = l2
  y : A
  l2' : list A
  IHl2' : eqb_list eqb (x :: l1') l2' = true <-> x :: l1' = l2'
  H0 : x = y
  H1 : l1' = l2'
  ============================
  x :: l1' = y :: l2'
```

Is there a tactic that allows me to apply `H0` and `H1` and complete this proof?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's called `rewrite` (see the [refman](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proofs/writing-proofs/rewriting.html?highlight=rewrite#coq:tacn.rewrite)). You can do

```
rewrite H0, H1.
```

or alternatively

```
rewrite H0.
rewrite H1.
```

EDIT: You can also use `f_equal` ([doc](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html?highlight=f_equal#coq:tacn.f_equal)), which should immediately discharge your goal.

Comment: hey, thanks a lot. I didn't know `rewrite` could be used like that :-) Should've tried, though